# Node exec child-process exits immediately

Tags: javascript, bash, child-process

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
echo "params:"
echo "ID: $1"
echo "Name: $2"

curl -u user:pass 
"https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('""$1""')/\$value" --
output $DIR/test/"$2".zip
wait
echo "download Product" "$2"
```

I call it through a node child process with this function:

```
function makeRequest(url, i, callback) {
var sys = require('util'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

var directory = __dirname.substring(0, __dirname.indexOf("\\app_api"));

console.log("executing:", directory + '\\downloadProducts.sh ' + url + ' ' + namesArray[i]);
child = exec(directory + '\\downloadProducts.sh ' + url + ' ' + namesArray[i]);
child.on("error", function (error) {
    console.log("child error:", error);

})

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());

});

child.on('close', function (exit) {
    console.log("child exit:", exit);

})
}
```

After this function is called, the child process exits with code 0, without waiting for the curl request to finish. I also tried `exit` instead of `close`.

How could I solve it? Thanks in advance.